# How to run a Python program without a window?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a program in Python that, when run, does not actually open any window (including command prompt)?

For example, opening the program would appear to do nothing, but in reality, the program is running in the background somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Can you give a little more information as to what you're trying to achieve and on which operating system?

Comment: The program I'm making just doesn't need a screen, and so I'd rather not have one. I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running the python program by double clicking `*.py` file in Windows?

Then, rename the `*.py` file to `*.pyw`.

Comment: If I use this way, how would I go about closing the program?

Comment: @Sim, Kill the process from task manager. The process name is `pythonw.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Run it with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`.